# How to declare two variables and run each separately through a method? (java)

Tags: java, class, methods, integer

So for an assignment I have to create an application whose `main()` method holds two variables. After declaring the variables and assigning an integer to each of them, I have to run both through the same 3 methods. I was thinking that I have to create a class for the variables, but honestly have no idea where to begin. So far, I have figured out how to run one of the integers through the methods, but I can't get both to pass through the same methods. 
Here is my work so far:

```
public class ArithmeticMethods{
    public class integer
    {
    int firstInteger = 10;
    int secondInteger = 20;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayNumberPlus10();
        displayNumberPlus100();
        displayNumberPlus1000();
        System.out.println(firstInteger + " +" + " 10" + " is " + displayNumberPlus10());
        System.out.println(firstInteger + " +" + " 100" + " is " + displayNumberPlus100());
        System.out.println(firstInteger + " +" + " 1000" + " is " + displayNumberPlus1000());
    }
     public static int displayNumberPlus10() {
        int numberPlus10;
        numberPlus10 = (firstInteger + 10);
        return numberPlus10;
    }
    public static int displayNumberPlus100() {
        int numberPlus100;
        numberPlus100 = (firstInteger + 100);
        return numberPlus100;
    }
    public static int displayNumberPlus1000() {
        int numberPlus1000;
        numberPlus1000 = (firstInteger + 1000);
        return numberPlus1000;
    }
}
```

Right now the methods are set to only run the first variable and with my ATTEMPT at creating a class, the program doesn't work at all. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Also I apologize if the code looks ugly. I am very new to this.

Comment: Do you know how to add parameters to your method? If not, read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: I read the article and I don't think I quite understand what I did wrong. I know I have to change the value firstInteger in the methods to something that represents both firstInteger and secondInteger, but after that, I don't have a clue what to change. I'm sorry if I come across as daft... It's a completely new language to me. I wish I understood what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parameters to your methods. The result should look something like this:

```
public static int displayNumberPlus10(int input) {
    return (input + 10);
}
...
```

And can be called like this:

```
int first = 10;
int second = 20;

displayNumberPlus10(first);
displayNumberPlus10(second);
```